# how to use jsdoc in local project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, jsdoc

### Goal

I want to use [jsdocs](http://usejsdoc.org/) with npm.

### Background

I am new to npm and its plugins. Recently I found out about jsdoc and I tried using it, with no success.

### What I tried

First I installed the package using npm's command `npm install --save jsdoc`, and the install completed successfully.

However, when I try to use it in my project (I am inside the project's folder) I type `jsdoc example.js` and I get the following error:

> /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/jsdoc: No such file or
>   directory

This leads me to think that:

- I am in the wrong directory. If so, where should I be? (other than the project root folder)
- The installation had a problem, even though it was successfull.

I have also tried to run `npm jsdoc example.js` but I get another error (this time from npm, saying I am not using it correctly).

I also installed jsdoc globally (using the `-g` flag) and it worked, but I truly want to avoid this because not all projects are using jsdoc.

### Summary

To conclude, I am looking for a way to run jsdoc locally to a project with npm. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run jsdoc in the command line, the location of the jsdoc needs to be known. So when you have installed jsdoc globally, system would be able to find the file.

However if you want to run it locally, you need to include the file location before the jsdoc command.

For example, try using `./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js example.js`

Comment: Is there a way for npm to know it automatically?

Comment: You can define it in package.json. Declare a command over there.

In package.json, under scripts declare the following,
`"jsdoc": "./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js example.js"` and then run `npm jsdoc'

Comment: Nice! I didn't remember that!

Comment: @ShriramManoharan - i get `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command` when running `npm run jsdoc` on Windows 10, even though `./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js example.js` works when entered directly in gitbash terminal.

Comment: hmm, this works for me in Windows 10 `package.json`:  `"make-my-docs": "jsdoc example.js -d ../my_docs_folder"` and then call it via terminal with `npm run make-my-docs`.  it seems calling with `npm run` assumes paths in script are in `node_modules` directory, per [this comment on a github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4040#issuecomment-59881464).  for reference, the `-d` flag allows docs to be created in folder outside of github repo [per docs](https://jsdoc.app/about-commandline.html)

Answer (score 0):

For local installation, the binary is in `node_modules/.bin/jsdoc`. If you install it globally, it should be accessible as `jsdoc` command. It's stated pretty early in the docs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc